# osmnx box is enlarged because of included 'natural' and 'land use' tags

Tags: osmnx

I'm building a dataset of walkable urban street forms with building footprints and natural areas (parks, hills, forests, meadows, etc.) for a comparative urbanism meets deep learning project for my bachelor thesis.

I want to create a dataset of 255 x 255 pixel images of maps of urban areas I've designed using osmnx. With OSMnx I query an area by a lon, lat point and then look at the bounding box of 700 meters around that point. However, my problem here is that the images can't be standardized to a 255 x 255 pixels size, because very often the green areas - like larger meadows or forests - enlarge the image to wholly fit into it, like in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGy50.png) of Montreal, Canada, where you can see how the green park area is kind of point out of the urban form. My question then would be, if you know any way of preventing this? Any method to fix the bounding box window and just cut off any excess green space that leeks out of it?

Any ideas will be very much appreciated.

Here is the code for used for to create the above image:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

center_point = (45.5016889, -73.567256)
center_dist = 700

graph = ox.graph_from_point(center_point, dist = center_dist, dist_type='bbox', network_type='walk')
nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))

edges.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, edgecolor='#BC8F8F')

leisure = ox.footprints_from_point(center_point, dist = center_dist, footprint_type="leisure")
parks = leisure[leisure["leisure"].isin(["pitch","park","playground"])]
parks.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="green")

natural = ox.footprints_from_point(center_point, dist = center_dist, footprint_type="natural")
natural_greens = natural[natural["natural"].isin(["tree","wood","grassland","tree_row","scrub","peak"])]
natural_greens.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="#90ee90")

landuse = ox.footprints_from_point(center_point, dist = center_dist, footprint_type="landuse")
landuse_greens = landuse[landuse["landuse"].isin(["meadow","forest","orchard","farmland","vineyard","farmyard","recreation_ground", "allotments"])]
landuse_greens.plot(ax=ax, facecolor="#FFF9C2")

buildings = ox.footprints_from_point(center_point, dist = center_dist)
buildings.plot(ax=ax, facecolor='#F73C6E', alpha=0.7)

plt.tight_layout()
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Consider using the OSMnx plotting functions, as they all take a `bbox` argument to constrain your plot. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62823755/7321942 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/64231028/7321942

Comment: Thank you for answering this promptly! This method solves problem I described above, but when it seems to create another one - the footprint geometries replace overwrite each other. If I plot the building footprints first and the leisure footprints on top, only the leisure footprints will be shown. Could you point me to some resources where this is adressed?

Comment: I considered combining multiple tags, so, 'leisure' and 'building':True, but then the buildings and leisure geometries would share the same color, whereas I need them to be of different colours in order for the neural net to be able to distinguish between them.

Comment: See the comments under https://stackoverflow.com/a/64231028/7321942

Comment: Thank you! But I've tried that. And this way I can either plot the buildings or the leisure areas - if I plot the  building footprints first and then the leisure areas, I'm only left with the leisure areas and the street network, and since I plotted the walkable form first, the parks are drawn on top of that, so it's not possible to see walkable part paths like in my original map above.  I really appreciate all this help! I know you must be busy with such questions, developing the system further and lecturing. Thank you, again!

Comment: I was using the plot_footprints in the wrong way, that is why the shapes were being drawn one over the other! After some trial and error, I managed to get it working the way I want. I can start building my dataset now, thank you for all the help and for this amazing software!